# iOS NSError with global handler

Tags: ios, objective-c, error-handling

I am in the beginning of programming an iOS app. Having read the Apple guides on how to deal with errors, I got the following most important points:

- Exceptions are for programmers
- Use `NSError` for the user

Now, `NSError` is usually passed as out-argument which can then be used inside and has to be checked by the caller. However, I'm asking myself whether it is a good idea to use a global error handler, say a singleton which wraps around `NSError` and could be used to trigger errors and error handling from within the called function.

Is there anything against that method or would it be a bad practice?

Comment: I've never seen the guide of which you speak, but I would guess that it's speaking from the viewpoint of an API programmer -- he would handle exceptions internally (if they're handled at all) and use NSErrors, not exceptions, to report problems to the API caller.

Comment: The guide I am referring to is [Dealing with Errors](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/ErrorHandling/ErrorHandling.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MacOS X has the concept of the [error responder chain](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ErrorHandlingCocoa/ErrorRespondRecover/ErrorRespondRecover.html), which is an informal protocol that propagates errors up the responder chain until they are handled. For whatever reason, this is not implemented in Cocoa on iOS, but several third party implementations exist:

[ErrorKit](https://github.com/hectr/ErrorKit)

[ios-presentError](https://github.com/kemenaran/ios-presentError)

There are several more out there.

This approach is very flexible, well documented, is a best practice on MacOS X, and is generally preferable to using a singleton for this purpose.

Comment: Had a look at ErrorKit, I think I'm going to use this because it kind of matches my initial idea.

Answer (score 0):

That would be an awful thing to do, because your point "NSError is for users" is not correct at all. NSErrors inform your software about the reasons why an operation couldn't be performed. Whether this is an error that the user needs to be told about depends entirely on the situation.

Comment: From the documentation: "Cocoa programs use NSError objects to convey information about runtime errors that users need to be informed about. " NSError encapsulates error information to be presented to a user. This is why it has localization, reasons and descriptions of the error, and recovery options. NSErrors are absolutely intended for user consumption.

Comment: @quellish - To most users the text in an NSError would be pure gibberish.  The practical purpose of them is to be logged to help diagnose bugs.

Comment: @HotLicks IMO it's clear not to present the raw content of the NSError to the user.

Answer (score 0):

In practice, most errors need to be handled in a very narrow context, and you will not gain anything by trying to wrap something around the NSError class. Just handle the error, and continue executing.

Answer (score 0):

Most exceptions in iOS are essentially "fatal" and cannot be handled effectively (and as a result it's unusual to use an exception handler in a iOS app).

By convention, non-fatal errors are reported with a return code or by returning a nil or zero from the called function.  In many of these cases an `error:` parameter is available which should be utilized (log/dump the resulting NSError value) when a bad return code is received.

(Note that the `error:` parm result is not what you check to see if an error occurred.  Rather, a bad return code elsewhere indicates that the `error:` parm result should be logged/dumped.)

There are very few cases where it makes sense to report the NSError contents to the user -- for the most part the information is meaningful only to the programmer.